# require_once is unable to find the file

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Hello i have a stupid question i search in stackflow there was lots of answeserd but i couldnt find solution for my problem i want to call a file in php receiving error actually the code is correct but i am receiving a problem error which is:

```
Warning: require_once(1) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or  directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Upload images\upload.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '1'(include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Upload
images\upload.php on line 2
```

I am using dreamweaver. i deleted the path with directory and recreated with different name but not solved still prob exist. also i did google there also i didn't find solution ???????    any one please my head is exploding....??????????????????????????????

Comment: here is my code:require_once('db.php') or mysql_error(); the db.php is in the same directory as my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test on my system reveals that `require_once("file") or error_function();` fails with that exact message; `require_once("file");` does not.

This is possibly because `require_once` is a statement rather than a function, and might have different parsing rules, causing your statement to actually be `require_once('db.php' or mysql_error());`. The PHP `or` operator with those arguments will return TRUE **without** calling `mysql_error`, causing the statement to be `require_once(1)` (`1 == TRUE`) - which would generate those messages. **This is just my speculation.**

### tl;dr

Try removing the  `or mysql_error()` from your code. `require_once` will generate a fatal error anyway. (Warning: Works On My Machine™.)

Comment: oo'ps i remove the     or mysql_error(); i received a blank white screen shows me that the code is not executed

Comment: If you're getting a blank white screen, that might just be the PHP running successfully but not printing anything. Throw an `echo("Test");` in at the end to see.

Comment: thanks i got the screen but php is not executing stackoverflow .com not leting me to paste the all code is there any way to paste my code for your checking

Comment: Put the code on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and paste the link here. Also, what do you mean by "php is not executing"?

Comment: thanks alot from your perfect  corporation actually there was one more or mysql_error i find it now probelem is solved i need your advise in my another probe if u have time ??????

Comment: You're welcome. (Yeah, I hate it when it turns out I only fixed the problem in half the places where it appeared...)

Comment: If you give me your email ID it will be your most kindness on me because I want to send you there with whole scenario and explanations.  my ID is tariq@tariq-hashemee.tk or tariq1341@gmail.com

Comment: By the way: If this answer solved the problem, consider accepting it (click the green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 1):

Try write complete path in require_once(path)

Comment: require_once('C:/xampp/htdocs/Upload images/db.php') or mysql_error();                 same not working  same error massage